# ReactJS serverside rendering ReactJS plugin in Developer Tools not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I use reactjs with asp.net mvc 5 and use html helpers with serverside rendering enabled. My components work as expected but ReactJS plugin in Chrome's Developer Tools shows the message:

> Waiting for roots to load...to reload the inspector

When I add `@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()` to the page, plugin starts to work since that line adds the initialization scripts for my components.

How can I make this plugin work in serverside rendering? I know that reactjs lacks some data attributes in serverside rendering mode, is this problem related to that one?